# Difficult Numerical Integral with special functions

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

### Context

I am trying to calculate some transport coefficients for a heat equation in confinement. The Boundaries are in the $x$ direction, and $y$ represents the parallel directions. This function essentially boils down to the following

$Q ( g , x ) = \int_0^1 dx' \int_0^\infty  \, dy' \int_0^1 dx'' \int_0^\infty  \, dy''  \, \int_0^1 dx_0 \int_0^\infty dT \, 
f(x' , x'') \, \times\frac{ y'( x - x')}{ ( g \,(x-x')^2 + {y'}^2 )^{3/2} }\frac{ y''(x' - x'')}{ ( g \,(x'-x'')^2 + {y''}^2 )^{3/2} },$

where we have

$f(x',x'') = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x' \partial x''} 
\frac{ e^{-\frac{{y''}^2}{8T}}}{T^2} \left( -1 + \frac{{y''}^2}{8 T} \right)[ \theta_3 ( \frac{\pi ( x' + x_0 )}{2},e^{-\pi^2 T})
+\theta_3 ( \frac{\pi ( x' - x_0 )}{2},e^{-\pi^2 T}) ] \times[ \theta_3 ( \frac{\pi ( x'' + x_0 )}{2},e^{-\pi^2 T})
+\theta_3 ( \frac{\pi ( x'' - x_0 )}{2},e^{-\pi^2 T})]$

and $\theta_3$ represents the [Jacobi Theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#A_solution_to_the_heat_equation) which solves the heat equation in confinement.

I want to plot the behavior of $Q(g,x=0)$ and $Q(g,x=1)$ for $ 0 < g < 2$

### Mathematica code

As a continuation of a [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225040/different-methods-in-nintegrate), I am now trying to numerically calculate the following integral:

```
hardintegral [  g_?NumericQ , x_?NumericQ ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  (Exp[-ypp^2/(8T)] / T^2) * ( -1 + ypp^2/(8T) ) * 
            ( EllipticThetaPrime[3, 1/2 Pi (xp + x0), Exp[-Pi^2 T] ] + 
                     EllipticThetaPrime[3, 1/2 Pi (xp - x0), Exp[-Pi^2 T] ] ) * 
            ( EllipticThetaPrime[3, 1/2 Pi (xpp + x0), Exp[-Pi^2 T] ] +  
                    EllipticThetaPrime[3, 1/2 Pi (xpp - x0), Exp[-Pi^2 T] ] ) *
( yp*(x-xp) / ( g*(x-xp)^2 + yp^2 )^(3/2) ) * ( ypp*(xp-xpp) / ( g*(xp-xpp)^2 + ypp^2 )^(3/2) ),
 {x0, 0, 1} , {T, 0, ∞}, {xp, 0, 1}  , {xpp, 0, 1} , {yp, 0, ∞}, {ypp, 0, ∞} ]
```

I want to get the following plots: `Plot[ hardintegral [g,0] , {g,0,2} ]` and
`Plot[ hardintegral [g,1] , {g,0,2} ]`. However, even obtaining a single result, for say `g=1.1` is taking a very long time on my computer. Using `Method->"GlobalAdaptive"` I get `2.83493*10^6` with the following error

```
NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. 
The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations.
Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. 
Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. 
NIntegrate obtained 2.8349279022111776`*^6 and 7.683067946598636`*^7 for the integral and error estimates.
```

Also, With `Method->"GaussKronrodRule` the computation goes on forever with no outcome.

Is there a way to speed up these integrations? I guess a possible solution for the plot then will be to use `ListPlot`.

### PS

The `yp` and `ypp` integrations can be done using `Integrate`. For example

```
Integrate[ Exp[-z^2/8T] * ( z / (a + z^2)^(3/2) ) , {z, 0, ∞}, Assumptions-> a>0 && T>0 ]
```

gives

```
( Gamma[1/2 (-1 + d)] HypergeometricU[ 1/2 (-1 + d), 1/2, a/(8 T) ] ) / (2 Sqrt[a])
```

Also for

```
Integrate[ Exp[-z^2/8T] * ( z^3 / (a + z^2)^(3/2) ) , {z, 0, ∞}, Assumptions-> a>0 && T>0 ]
```

the result is

```
1/2 Sqrt[a] * ( Gamma[1/2 (1 + d)] HypergeometricU[ 1/2 (1 + d), 3/2, a/(8 T) ] )
```

I tried plugging these back into the `NIntegrate` but it doesn't seem to do much in terms of the speed.

Comment: Instead of Plot, do a ListLinePlot on a Table e.g `ParallelTable[{g,hardintegral [g,0]} , {g,1,3,0.1}]`. The advantage is you control the step size and you can do it in parallel. Also have you tried the MonteCarlo methods for NIntegrate? They may be faster.

Comment: @flinty thanks, I was thinking of just a normal Table, but probably a parallel one is faster. And yes I tried MC ones, but the results are too unreliable and I don't know if I can make sense of them.

Comment: @SaMaSo It looks like integral does not depend on `x` and diverges at `T->0`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Ah my bad! the mathematica code is the correct formula, but I had made a mistake in the formula I gave in for context. Will correct it, thanks

Comment: @AlexTrounev This is what I understand: for $y'' \neq 0$, the integral doesn't diverge for $T -> 0$ because of the  ```Exp[- ypp^2 / (8T)]``` factor. For $y'' = 0$ the contribution is zero because of the second fraction.

Comment: @SaMaSo In a new redaction we have integral on T with $\theta_3' $ only. Is it correct?

Comment: @AlexTrounev thanks again. I corrected it.

Comment: @SaMaSo Unfortunately integral  diverges at `T->0`. So we can regularized it by cutting integral over `ypp` like `{ypp, eps, Infinity}` with `eps>0` or over `T` with `eps=10^-2`. With the last assumption I have a solution.

Comment: @AlexTrounev yes you are right. Then the cutoff you mention sounds a good plan.

Comment: @AlexTrounev it seems that the divergence depends on whether you substitute $f(x',x'')$ in $Q$ first and then try to perform all the integrations, or try to perform the integrals on involved in $f$ first and insert the result into $Q$. The latter has a divergent term for $y''=0$ as you mentioned, but the former does not seem to have that

Answer (score 6):

We can integrate in 3 steps:

```
Integrate[(yp/(b + yp^2)^(3/2)), {yp, 0, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> b > 0]*(x - xp) /. {b -> 
    g (x - xp)^2} //Simplify

Out[]: (x - xp)/Sqrt[g (x - xp)^2]
```

So we have `intyp=1/Sqrt[g]` as results and it means that `Q[g,x]` not depends on `x`. Next step:

```
Integrate[(Exp[-ypp^2/(8 T)])*(-1 + 
   ypp^2/(8 T)) (ypp/(g*(xp - xpp)^2 + ypp^2)^(3/2)), {ypp, 0, Infinity},  Assumptions ->{...}]
```

I made substitutions `s->ypp/Sqrt[8 T], a->g*(xp - xpp)^2/(8 T)`, it turns into

```
Integrate[
 Exp[-s^2] (-1 + s^2) s/(a + s^2)^(3/2), {s, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0}]

Out[]= -((1 + a)/Sqrt[a]) + 
 1/2 (3 + 2 a) E^a Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erfc[Sqrt[a]]
```

Restoring all coefficient coming from `ypp` normalization on `Sqrt[8 T]` we have

```
intypp= 
With[{a = g*(xp - xpp)^2/(8 T)}, 
 Sqrt[8 T]/(8 T)^(3/2) Sqrt[
    8 T] (-((1 + a)/Sqrt[a]) + 1/2 (3 + 2 a) E^a Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erfc[Sqrt[a]]) //
   Simplify]

Out[]=
(-((8*(1 + (g*(xp - xpp)^2)/(8*T)))/Sqrt[(g*(xp - xpp)^2)/T]) + 
   E^((g*(xp - xpp)^2)/(8*T))*Sqrt[2*Pi]*(3 + (g*(xp - xpp)^2)/(4*T))*
    Erfc[Sqrt[(g*(xp - xpp)^2)/T]/(2*Sqrt[2])])/(8*Sqrt[T])
```

Therefore we get integrand

```
intp intpp (xp - xpp)/T^2 (EllipticTheta[3, 1/2 Pi (xp + x0), Exp[-Pi^2 T]] + 
   EllipticTheta[3, 1/2 Pi (xp - x0), Exp[-Pi^2 T]])*(EllipticTheta[3,
     1/2 Pi (xpp + x0), Exp[-Pi^2 T]] + 
   EllipticTheta[3, 1/2 Pi (xpp - x0), Exp[-Pi^2 T]])
```

And finally we have

```
int2[g_, x0_, T_, xp_, 
  xpp_] := (EllipticTheta[3, 1/2 Pi (xp + x0), Exp[-Pi^2 T]] + 
    EllipticTheta[3, 1/2 Pi (xp - x0), 
     Exp[-Pi^2 T]])*(EllipticTheta[3, 1/2 Pi (xpp + x0), 
      Exp[-Pi^2 T]] + 
     EllipticTheta[3, 1/2 Pi (xpp - x0), 
      Exp[-Pi^2 T]])/(8 T^3) (-2 Sqrt[
      2 T] (1 + (g (xp - xpp)^2)/(8 T))/Sqrt[g ] + 
     1/2 E^((g (xp - xpp)^2)/(8 T))
       Sqrt[\[Pi]] (3 + (g (xp - xpp)^2)/(4 T)) Erfc[Sqrt[(
       g (xp - xpp)^2)/T]/(2 Sqrt[2])]*(xp - xpp))/Sqrt[g] Sqrt[8 T]
```

This is what we can work with. But it diverges at `T->0`. We can perform numerical integration cutting of temperature limits as follows

```
hardintegral[g_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  int2[g, x0, T, xp, xpp], {x0, 0, 1}, {xp, 0, 1}, {xpp, 0, 1}, {T, 
   10^-2, 10}, AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 2]
```

The upper limits `T` does not matter since integrand very fast vanished at `T>1`  , but `T=10^-2` is essential for fast calculations. So we make a table and plot

```
 lst = Table[{g, hardintegral[g]}, {g, .1, 2, .1}]  
    ListLinePlot[lst, PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"g", "Q"}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Figure 1]

I can recommend to use function `Q[g,T]` for future research. We can define function

```
Q[g_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  int2[g, x0, T, xp, xpp], {x0, 0, 1}, {xp, 0, 1}, {xpp, 0, 1}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 2]
```

Now we plot it to check singularity at `g->0` and `T->0`:

```
Plot3D[Q[g, T], {g, .1, 2}, {T, .1, 2}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: +1. Nice breakdown, However, I think the cut-off `T=10^-2` is arbitrary and unwarranted. Nonetheless, it does bring focus on the problem, and that is helpful.  Not convinced that it diverges at `T->0`, but there are problems around `10^-6 < T < 10^-2`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I agree with you that my approach is only 3 steps of 5 to solve this problem. Next 2 steps could be around properties of function `Q[g_, T_]:=NIntegrate[
 int2[g, x0, T, xp, xpp], {x0, 0, 1}, {xp, 0, 1}, {xpp, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you very much. This looks on the right track. I have a question: as it is, you are performing the ```T``` integration after ```ypp``` (which I like) - but doesn't this mean there shouldn't be a singularity in ```T```?

Comment: @SaMaSo There is a singularity `1/T^2`on a hypersurface `ypp=0`. And we can't remove it, but we can cut of `T` as I did. It is a reason why your `hardintegral`  has no stable result.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I am not fully sure again, because ```ypp=0``` is also multiplied in the numerator, so it is ambiguous.

Comment: @AlexTrounev If you make the substitution ```T -> 1 / u```  ( which also means $d u \to - dT / T^2$ ), then the integrated looks regular except in the second argument of the ```EllipticTheta``` which would be ```Exp[ - Pi^2 / u ]```.  I plot ```EllipticTheta``` with this latter argument, and it doesn't seem to be singular.

Comment: @SaMaSo Just put `ypp=0` and check that integral with `u=1/T` diverges  at `u->Infinity`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you. Could you specify what are the assumptions for the second integrate ( on ypp )?  
Just for completeness,  regarding the ```x``` independence you mentioned, I observe for ```x=0``` or ```x=1``` (which are the cases here) the expression differs in an overall sign. But for intermediate values of x, this gets a bit more complicated

Comment: @AlexTrounev  I am now checking the last ```NIntegrate``` with option ```Methods -> ''GaussKronrodRule'' ```. It takes quite a while, but seems the results are relatively close to what you got. Please could you elaborate a bit on how construct ```int2```? I guess you just insert the result of the first three integrations into the related parts in my integrand, but if you could give those integrations a name and insert them that makes it more clear.

Comment: @AlexTrounev your answer has been really helpful, thank you. The ```GaussKronrodRule``` took very long, so I eventually modified other options of the ```NIntegrate``` to get more accurate results. I might update the post later, but they are relatively close to what I get from your approach. I also suspect that there is a delta function hidden in the integrand, and will work on that.

Comment: @SaMaSo You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the number of integration in `NIntegrate` seems reasonable. The effects are somehow dependent on the choices of options for `NIntegrate`.

Choices are

Values for lower integral bounds larger than zero.
Values replacing the infinite upper bound of the integral to a meaningful numerical integration value.

The default method is `GlobalAdaptive`. This can be changed.

`GlobalAdaptive` has the method option `MaxErrorIncreases` that governs the time needed or spend by NIntegrate in this question very much. `MaxErrorIncreases` takes time and is always used to full extend.

WorkingPrecision should be set high according to persisting error messages.

Leave most of the work to `NIntegrate` is in general very good advice. A best practice recommendation from Wolfram Inc and its competitors.

This works moderately crude:

```
Nn = 10^6; eps = 10^-8; Table[
 ListPlot[Last[
   Reap[NIntegrate[(EllipticThetaPrime[3, 1/2 Pi (xp + x0), 
         Exp[-Pi^2 T]] + 
        EllipticThetaPrime[3, 1/2 Pi (xp - x0), 
         Exp[-Pi^2 T]])*(EllipticThetaPrime[3, 1/2 Pi (xpp + x0), 
         Exp[-Pi^2 T]] + 
        EllipticThetaPrime[3, 1/2 Pi (xpp - x0), 
         Exp[-Pi^2 T]])*(0.2727575560073645` - 
        0.6266570686577505` E^(1.6801824043209879` T) Sqrt[T] + 
        0.6266570686577502` E^(1.6801824043209879` T) Sqrt[T]
          Erf[1.2962185017661907` Sqrt[T]])*(Integrate[
        Exp[-z^2/8 T]*(z^3/(g + z^2)^(3/2)), {z, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
        Assumptions -> g > 0 && T > 0]), {x0, eps, 1}, {T, eps, 
      Nn}, {xp, eps, 1}, {xpp, eps, 1}, {g, eps, 2}, 
     Method -> {str, "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 15}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 50, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[g]]]], 
  PlotLabel -> str], {str, {"GlobalAdaptive", "LocalAdaptive", 
   "Trapezoidal", "DoubleExponential"}}]
```

This output is a bunch of error messages and the desired plot.

Higher upper bound and smaller lower bound offer convergence independent of the value of MaxErrorIncrease.

This might perform even better with compilations and parallel processing.

I soon will continue this answer.

Comment: Thank you for this. There was a mistake in the formula I had provided for context (the one for Mathematica code was correct though), and I have edited this.

Comment: I don't seem to understand to understand your approach, especially what those numbers in the exponentials etc are, and why there is sqrt of T. Would be good if you could add explanations later

Comment: for ```Methods```, based on the previous post that I linked in the question, it could be that the GaussKronrod is the best.

Comment: The output of you code is http://i.stack.imgur.com/vrmjJ.png, which seems useless. Why do you think it's worth posting?

Comment: @SteffenJaeschke Option `WorkingPrecision -> 50` is not applicable to the integrand with numbers like `0.2727575560073645`,